# How to restore obfuscated property names?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

So I'm decrypting a javascript code, and after long time of looking on the internet I have no clue on how to decrypt this a quick way.

The code starts off with a large Array containing all strings of the entire script.

```
 var _$_21e2 = ["jQuery", "userAgent", "test", "onmouseup", "onmousemove", "pink", "greenyellow", "gold"]
```

There are more string in the array, but this is just an example.

And then in the rest of the code it just calls the string from the array, by id.

```
_$_21e2[29]
```

I know I can just do this manually but there are around 120 strings so it would be taking too much time to do this.
Is there a way to quickly decrypt this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Truly sorry about the codes, they were meant to be like codes but I'm new to StackOverflow, please don't mind

Comment: Fixed it. All you needed was another line between each code block and the preceding paragraph :).

Comment: Why do you need to de-obfuscate this?

Comment: I need the code, someone managed to obfuscate it, I want to know how to deobfuscate. I made this with him but he won't give me the original code.

Comment: You can try http://jsbeautifier.org/ but generally it will only apply readable names to variables and such, as for replacing all the variables with the strings, that would normally be done in an editor with search and replace

Comment: This isn't "encryption". Encryption uses a code and a key. This is obfuscation which is a type of "encoding", not a type of "encryption". Encoding changes the format of a code with*out* a key. It's a subtle difference, but enough that I think "encryption" should be removed as a tag from this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [regex `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will do:

```
var _$_21e2 = ["jQuery", "userAgent", "test", "onmouseup", "onmousemove", "pink", "greenyellow", "gold"];
return code.replace(/\[_\$_21e2\[(\d+)\]\]/g, function(_, i) {
    return "."+_$_21e2[i];
}).replace(/_\$_21e2\[(\d+)\]/g, function(_, i) {
    return JSON.stringify(_$_21e2[i]);
});
```

Given the `code` as a string, this will yield a code string with human-readable property names and literals.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how would I use this?

Comment: As I said, with your script as a string in the `code` variable.

Comment: Doesn't work, every string from array gets back as "undefined"
Example:
for (bz = (3 * bz + u) / 4, bH = (3 * bH + bq) / 4, W.undefined(), W.undefined = undefined, W.undefined = 10, W.undefined = undefined, W.undefined = undefined, W.undefined = 0.5, W.undefined(), bn = 0; bn < X.undefined; bn++) {
                W.undefined(X[bn].undefined, X[bn].undefined), W.undefined(bz, bH)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, works exactly how I want it to!