# JavaScript array deobfuscation

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex, deobfuscation

Solved: [Replace array-mapped variables with the actual variable name/string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627158/replace-array-mapped-variables-with-the-actual-variable-name-string)

I'm trying to decode some JS and I've got a good portion of it done, however, I'm stumped here. The code does something like this:

```
var arr = ["value", "value1", "value2"];
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Except the file is around 12k lines and there are over 1.4k things in the array.
Is there a way I can replace `arr[0]` with the actual value of `arr[0]` (in the example, it would be "value"), then save the file? I tried using RegExp but got nowhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you write to write the output into a file? `node script.js > myfile.txt`

Comment: @Rahul I tried to iterate through it and then replace the array and value with the actual one but I just couldn't work the logic out.

Comment: @EliR: Please add that in your post along with code if possible.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the nature of your file (share a small sample)? What output are you looking for from it?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I can't post a snippet right now, but the file is JS code. I'm trying to replace the array name and index (ex: arr[0]), with the actual value of it (ex: "value").

Comment: So, you are trying to use regex on Javascript code?

Comment: Though many details are missing. I don't think it's a good idea to just search for `arr[0]` and replace with `value`.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Code parsed as a multi-line string, yes.

Comment: @EliR: `1.4k things in the array.` In one array itself ?

Comment: I think it is better to simply let the method load as-is and then override that method with yours after it has been loaded.

Comment: @Rahul Yes. Just one array. It has been obfuscated. I've fixed most of it, but having this array thing fixed would make it much more readable.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I could try that, it's just very difficult to read with the array because I have to keep checking to see what the value is.

Comment: Do you only need to replace `0` index with its corresponding value?

Comment: @revo Sadly, no. I have to replace all indexes. (0-1.4k)

Comment: So for example there would be `arr[254]` in file which you want to replace as well?

Comment: @revo Yes. I don't think they are in perfect order, and some are used more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple idea would be having arrays in current scope and use target javascript file content as input string for `replace()` method:

```js
var arr = ['hello', 'my', 'world']
var str = `
var arr = ['hello', 'my', 'world']
console.log('arr[2]')
console.log('arr[0]')
console.log('arr[1]')
`
console.log(str.replace(/\b(\w+)\[(\d+)]/g, function(match, $p1, $p2) {
   return window[$p1][$p2];
}))
```

​