# How can I decode this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, decode

I want to decode the following script but can't seem to get it in working state.
I tried to decode it on http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/ but can't understand the first few lines.

```
var _0x2a14=["\x7B","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7B\x2E\x75\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x57\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x2C\x2E\x66\x62\x55\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7B\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x7B\x68\x61\x73\x2D\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x7B\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7B\x6E\x65\x78\x74\x7B\x2E\x75\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x3A\x6C\x61\x73\x74\x7B\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x7B\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x7B\x68\x61\x73\x7B\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7B\x61\x74\x74\x72\x7B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2D\x69\x64\x7B\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2D\x69\x64\x5D\x7B\x69\x73\x4E\x75\x6D\x65\x72\x69\x63\x7B\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7B\x61\x5B\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x74\x68\x65\x61\x74\x65\x72\x5D\x7B\x24\x31\x7B\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7B\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x69\x66\x79\x7B\x65\x61\x63\x68\x7B\x61\x7B\x76\x61\x6C\x7B\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x66\x74\x5F\x65\x6E\x74\x5F\x69\x64\x65\x6E\x74\x69\x66\x69\x65\x72\x5D\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x69\x64\x3D\x27\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x7B\x27\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x27\x3E\x7B\x3C\x66\x69\x65\x6C\x64\x73\x65\x74\x3E\x7B\x3C\x6C\x65\x67\x65\x6E\x64\x3E\x7B\x3C\x61\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x46\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x20\x56\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x20\x2D\x20\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x27\x3E\x7B\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x27\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2F\x66\x61\x76\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x2F\x66\x62\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2F\x66\x61\x76\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x2D\x33\x32\x78\x33\x32\x2E\x70\x6E\x67\x27\x20\x2F\x3E\x7B\x50\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x62\x79\x20\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x7B\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x7B\x3C\x2F\x6C\x65\x67\x65\x6E\x64\x3E\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x7B\x43\x61\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x67\x65\x74\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x73\x20\x6F\x66\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x6F\x6E\x20\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x66\x65\x65\x64\x2E\x20\x3C\x62\x72\x20\x2F\x3E\x7B\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x20\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x20\x6F\x6E\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x2D\x3E\x20\x53\x68\x6F\x77\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x55\x52\x4C\x20\x2D\x3E\x20\x43\x6F\x70\x79\x20\x55\x72\x6C\x20\x2D\x3E\x20\x50\x61\x73\x74\x65\x20\x55\x72\x6C\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x6E\x65\x77\x20\x74\x61\x62\x2E\x20\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x73\x20\x77\x69\x6C\x6C\x20\x62\x65\x20\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x6E\x20\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x72\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2E\x20\x3C\x62\x72\x20\x2F\x3E\x7B\x49\x66\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x73\x20\x68\x61\x76\x65\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x6E\x2C\x20\x70\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x68\x72\x6F\x6D\x65\x2E\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x77\x65\x62\x73\x74\x6F\x72\x65\x2F\x64\x65\x74\x61\x69\x6C\x2F\x61\x77\x65\x73\x6F\x6D\x65\x2D\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x2D\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2D\x64\x6F\x2F\x6B\x6D\x6D\x69\x6E\x6A\x6F\x6F\x65\x6D\x6D\x68\x68\x62\x70\x6B\x62\x66\x6D\x6A\x68\x6B\x6E\x66\x66\x70\x6C\x6D\x6A\x6B\x66\x69\x2F\x73\x75\x70\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x27\x3E\x72\x65\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x64\x65\x76\x20\x74\x65\x61\x6D\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x2E\x7B\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x7B\x3C\x2F\x66\x69\x65\x6C\x64\x73\x65\x74\x3E\x7B\x61\x66\x74\x65\x72\x7B\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x49\x64\x7B\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x55\x72\x6C\x7B\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x7B\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x55\x72\x6C\x7B\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x73\x2F\x7B\x68\x64\x7B\x2F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2D\x68\x64\x2E\x6D\x70\x34\x7B\x73\x64\x7B\x2F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2D\x73\x64\x2E\x6D\x70\x34\x7B\x23\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x66\x69\x78\x27\x3E\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x70\x75\x6C\x6C\x2D\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x27\x3E\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x70\x75\x6C\x6C\x2D\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x2D\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x73\x27\x3E\x20\x3C\x62\x3E\x4C\x6F\x61\x64\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x2E\x2E\x2E\x3C\x2F\x62\x3E\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x2D\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x20\x35\x70\x78\x3B\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x3A\x20\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x27\x3E\x7B\x2D\x2D\x2D\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x20\x7B\x3C\x61\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x7B\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x56\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x55\x72\x6C\x27\x3E\x7B\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2F\x65\x6D\x62\x65\x64\x3F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x7B\x73\x64\x5F\x73\x72\x63\x5F\x6E\x6F\x5F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6C\x69\x6D\x69\x74\x3A\x22\x7B\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7B\x73\x64\x5F\x73\x72\x63\x5F\x6E\x6F\x5F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6C\x69\x6D\x69\x74\x22\x3A\x22\x7B\x22\x7B\x2F\x7B\x68\x64\x5F\x73\x72\x63\x5F\x6E\x6F\x5F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6C\x69\x6D\x69\x74\x3A\x22\x7B\x68\x64\x5F\x73\x72\x63\x5F\x6E\x6F\x5F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6C\x69\x6D\x69\x74\x22\x3A\x22\x7B\x53\x44\x20\x69\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x61\x76\x61\x69\x6C\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x7B\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x62\x74\x6E\x20\x62\x74\x6E\x2D\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x2D\x73\x64\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x7B\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x53\x44\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x27\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x3D\x27\x46\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x7B\x20\x53\x44\x20\x2D\x20\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2E\x6D\x70\x34\x27\x3E\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x53\x44\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x7B\x48\x44\x20\x69\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x61\x76\x61\x69\x6C\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x7B\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x62\x74\x6E\x20\x62\x74\x6E\x2D\x70\x72\x69\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x62\x6F\x6C\x64\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x2D\x68\x64\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x7B\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x48\x44\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x27\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x3D\x27\x46\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x7B\x20\x48\x44\x20\x2D\x20\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2E\x6D\x70\x34\x27\x3E\u21E9\x20\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x48\x44\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x7B\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7B\x20\x2E\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x2D\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E\x73\x7B\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x7B\x54\x68\x69\x73\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x64\x6F\x65\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x68\x61\x76\x65\x20\x61\x6E\x79\x20\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x73\x7B\x20\x53\x44\x20\x7B\x77\x7B\x78\x7B\x68\x7B\x20\x2D\x20\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2E\x6D\x70\x34\x27\x3E\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x53\x44\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x7B\x20\x48\x44\x20\x7B\x20\x2D\x20\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2E\x6D\x70\x34\x27\x3E\u21E9\x20\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x48\x44\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x7B\x67\x65\x74\x7B\x2E\x75\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x57\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x2C\x2E\x66\x62\x55\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x3A\x6E\x6F\x74\x28\x2E\x68\x61\x73\x2D\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x29\x7B\x2E\x75\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x57\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x72\x7B\x2E\x66\x62\x55\x73\x65\x72\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7B\x31\x7B\x6C\x6F\x67\x7B\x61\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2D\x69\x64\x5D\x7B\x73\x64\x20\x68\x64\x7B\x2E\x6D\x74\x6D\x2E\x5F\x35\x70\x63\x6D\x3A\x6E\x6F\x74\x28\x2E\x68\x61\x73\x2D\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x29\x7B\x23\x70\x65\x72\x6D\x61\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x5F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x5F\x70\x61\x67\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x7B\x65\x78\x65\x63\x7B\x68\x61\x73\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x27\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x2D\x62\x6F\x74\x74\x6F\x6D\x3A\x20\x31\x30\x70\x78\x27\x3E\x7B\x20\x50\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x65\x64\x20\x62\x79\x20\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x7B\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x66\x69\x78\x27\x3E\x44\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x20\x61\x74\x20\x68\x65\x72\x65\x3A\x20\x7B\x3C\x61\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x66\x62\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x73\x2F\x7B\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74"];
```

Comment: Just paste it in the console and you will get back the string values without escape sequences.

Comment: Have you actually tried that? Doesn't work for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627158/replace-array-mapped-variables-with-the-actual-variable-name-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to see the actual content, follow below steps :

1. Go to Google Chrome Console.
2. Copy your content and paste it.
3. Then print the variable using **console.log(_0x2a14);**

Below is what I got on my console.

[image]

Comment: console says undefined

Comment: You should do something like `console.log("\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74")` and not put the whole line in console.